# Checking array input value Verilog

Tags: verilog

How can I check the value of array input in Verilog? I tried this code but, I got an error "**op_code is not a constant**"

```
module mutlti_proccessor(data_out, flags, data_1, data_2, op_code);
    input [7:0]data_1;
    input [7:0]data_2;      
    input [3:0]op_code;

    output [7:0]data_out;
    output [4:0]flags;
    /* flags[0]:ZF "Zero Flag", flags[1]:SF "Sign Flag", flags[2]:CF "Carry Flag", 
       flags[3]:OF "Overflow Flag", flags[4]:COF "Compare Flag" */

    wire carry;

    /* Set falgs to zero */
    assign {flags[0], flags[1], flags[2], flags[3], flags[4]} = {1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0 };

    if(op_code==00000)
        Ripple_Adder RA1(data_out, carry, data_1, data_2, 0);


endmodule
```

Where Ripple_ADD is another module that sums up two 8-bit numbers.
**Note**: *there is no clock*.

Thanks ....

Comment: I'm getting an error **A is not an constant**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the line of code:

```
if(op_code==00000)
     Ripple_Adder RA1(data_out, carry, data_1, data_2, 0);
```

You don't seem to have understood that Verilog is a "Hardware Description Language", not a procedural programming language. It does *not* execute code line by line, but rather is synthesized into hardware based on what you are describing.

You are trying to use an `if` statement incorrectly. What your code is describing is that if the `op_code` is 0, then create some hardware called `Ripple_Adder`. However, what happens if `op_code` is not 0? Does it need to infer the adder? Should it delete the adder?

Simple answer, it can't - the hardware is fixed at synthesis, you can't add or remove bits of it when running. This is why it is complaining about `op_code` not being a constant - it doesn't know whether or not `Ripple_Adder` should be included or not.

The solution, is to always include the hardware, and then infer a multiplexer to select whether or not the output of it is used. Something like this:

```
wire [7:0] ripple_data_out; //Output data for the ripple adder
Ripple_Adder RA1(ripple_data_out, carry, data_1, data_2, 0); //Infer the ripple adder

always @ * begin
    case (op_code)
        5'b00000: data_out = ripple_data_out; //If the op_code matches, connect ripple_data_out to data_out through the mux.
        //... Add more cases here for other op_code values ...
        default: data_out = 8'b0;
    endcase
end
```

Comment: @White159 I'd suggest reading through [this](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day.html) tutorial. I found it quite useful when I first started with Verilog.

Comment: I am sorry ... I have another question: If we have a variable to be set in multi_proccessor module, CF: carry flag, which is set inside Ripple_Adder module, how can I do it?

Comment: @White159 Same way as the data_out, infer a mux.